# How can I retain the value of an object in a block?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, properties, weak-references

**Scenario:**

I have a Parse `PFObject` (which is a subclass of `NSObject)` declared:

```
 PFObject *Event = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Event"];
```

Later I have a `CLGeocoder`:

```
CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
CLLocation *loc = ...

[ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
                    preferredLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pl_PL"]
                  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                      CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                      if (placemark) {

                          Event[@"StreetName"] = ...

                      }
                  }
];
```

**Problem:**

When I want to save this `PFObject` by calling `[Event save]` (outside of the block) , all fields inside Event are uploaded except this one in the block because the value is not kept outside of the block.

**My approach:**

I think it can help to actually create a weak property, but for some reason then I click the button that triggers the IBAction where all of the above is enclosed in, nothing happens.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an async concept you are missing, or `__block` you are looking for.

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with executing the block on the main thread or not , but I’m pretty sure that the __block can only be used for primitive data types.

Comment: If you call `[Event save]` outside the block, it will run before `reverseGeocodeLocation` has executed and `Event[@"StreetName"]` is assigned because `reverseGeocodeLocation` is an async method. So you can't do that. If you want to use the result of `reverseGeocodeLocation` to call `[Event save]`, you will have to do do it inside the `completionHandler` block.

Comment: *that the __block can only be used for primitive data types* Yes this is because only "primitive" data types are captured. If you capture a pointer, esp. an object reference, inside a block, the value of the pointer is kept, not the object it points to. The object itself is volatile. – But this has nothing to do with your Q. @Davi is right.